# Is this softmax activation function using torch.exp() correct?

Tags: python, pytorch, softmax

I am trying to develop a function for softmax activation. The function should do torch.Tensor, 2D matrix with sum over rows is 1.

Is this function correct?

```
def softmax(x):
    return torch.exp(x)/torch.sum(torch.exp(x), dim=1).view(-1,1)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to use it?

Answer (score 0):

This is calculating the sum over columns because of using dim=1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).